# how to publish comments automatically in different facebook walls

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, authentication, facebook-wall

I'm developing a web-page in codeigniter with a login and private section for users. In that private section, the users will have the option to introduce their facebook login and password.

What I would like is to publish automatically on their walls some activity of the webpage just click-ing in a button. I don't know if the  approach is correct or if it is possible to do. Does anyone know if it is possible or if a tutorial exists in that subject?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be asking for user's facebook passwords. The Facebook API will handle the login process for you. From there, you can easily publish stuff back to Facebook. If you ask for the `publish_stream` or `publish_action` permission, you will be able to post stuff to facebook in the background.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the FB.api:

Documentation:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

Tutorial:
http://daipratt.co.uk/using-fb-api-to-make-a-full-post-to-a-users-wall/